# Kernel density estimation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst, kernel-density

[image]

I am using ArcGIS 10.2.2, I am trying to run Kernel Density Estimation on roads to Identify Car Crash hotspots, with ArcGIS 9.3 there is an option "Analysis mask" that one can use so that the analysis focuses strictly on input. I can't find such an option in ArcGIS 10.2.2, that's why the results include even the part were there are no roads, I want the focus to be only on the roads.

Comment: What you mean by ArcGis in contrast to ArcGis 10.2.2? If you only want it for the streets you can extract it...

Comment: I meant ArcGIS 9.3, that option is not available in ArcGIS 10.2.2

Comment: Goto environment settings, set mask

Comment: I checked under environmental settings, I can't find something like that

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to create a road buffer polygon using the road polyline shapefile to use as a mask. To set a mask go to Envirionmental Settings > Raster Analysis > Mask as suggested by @FelixIP.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w0000001t00000